Update Firebase realtime database stats before electron app quit
I have the following code:
app.on('before-quit', (event) => {
  console.log("IT IS BEFORE QUIT")
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("default prevented")
  setUserStatusOffline().then(() => {
    console.log("User status set to offline, quitting app.");
    app.quit()
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error("Error setting user status to offline:", error)
    app.quit()
  });
});

function setUserStatusOffline() {
  console.log("set offline called")
  const userRef = ref(database, `/users/${userId}/status`)
  console.log("UR",userRef)
  return set(userRef, 'offline')
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Success: User status set to offline')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error setting user status to offline:', error)
      throw error
    })
}

What I want it to be doing is executing the Firebase user status update, and then quitting. If I just attempt to call setUserStatusOffline() in my before-quit the app quits but status is never set, presumably because the app quits first.
In this case what happens is the following is logged:
IT IS BEFORE QUIT
default prevented
set offline called

but then neither the success nor the error message log, I don't get any other errors, and the app doesn't quit. I don't want to use onDisconnect because this is a mac menubar app – onDisconnect fires when I close the window, even if it's still running in the menubar.
